# Create Table in MySQL with Exactly One not NULL value in a combination of columns

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables namely:

**1. department_heads**

- DepartmentID
- StaffID

**2. sub_department_heads**

- SubDepartmentID
- StaffID

**3. branch_managers**

- BranchID
- StaffID

Now what I want is not have staff being a department head as well as a branch manager or sub department head and vise verse.

Staff can only belong in only one table.

Kindly advice on how i can structure my tables. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine 3 tables to one. For example (schematically)

```sql
CREATE TABLE Heads (
    StaffID PRIMARY KEY,
    DepartmentID FOREIGN KEY,
    SubDepartmentID FOREIGN KEY,
    BranchID FOREIGN KEY,
    CHECK (DepartmentID IS NULL + SubDepartmentID IS NULL + BranchID IS NULL = 2)
);
```

Comment: Thanks @Akina for your kind advice, I think this will work for me, But clarify for what this line - CHECK (DepartmentID IS NULL + SubDepartmentID IS NULL + BranchID IS NULL = 1) - means. Thanks

Comment: @MasabaJamesMoses `column IS NULL` produces either 1 or 0. So the whole expression checks that only one of these 3 columns is set to a value, and another two are NULL, and hence CHECK prevents insertion/edition for the row when this condition fails. A typo in this constraint is fixed.

Comment: Thanks very Much. Finally figured it out using using your approach. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. @Akina Thanks for your contribution.

```
CREATE TABLE `heads` (
  `StaffId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `DeptId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SubDeptId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BranchId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`StaffId`),
  CONSTRAINT `heads_chk_1` CHECK ((`DeptId` is not null) + (`SubDeptId` is not null) + (`BranchId` is not null) = 1)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```